# Remove CustomCell from table

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I am using the delegate method of NSURLConnection in UITableViewCell(CustomCell). I am showing the download progress in the cell. When the download completes, connectionDidFinishLoading is called. I need to remove the cell where I show the download progress, once the download completes. It is explained in the below image.

[image]

Here the download of the file in the third cell is completed first and the downloads in the other two cell are in progress. I need to delete the cell once the download completes. In this case, I have to delete the third cell in which the download was completed.
So, somebody help me to remove the cell in connectionDidFinishLoading. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while creating cell set the tag 

cell.tag=55;

in connectdidFinishing u can remove it by

[[self.view viewWithTag:55] removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start download and update custom cell to show progress, save indexPath somewhere in you delegate

in header:

```
NSIndexPath *targetCellIP;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSIndexPath *targetCellIP;
```

in implementation:

```
@synthesize targetCellIP;

// Somewhere where you update cell layout to show progress save it's indexPath
[self setTargetCellIP:....];

// After download is completed, remove cell from data model
[[dataModel objectAtIndex:[targetCellIP section]] 
                                        removeObjectAtIndex:[targetCellIP row]];

// Remove cell from table
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:targetCellIP] 
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
```

This method will be good only if you have only one cell with progress which you want to remove, in other case, you can store indices in array and use them when ether you need them.

Comment: or, you could save it in an array and then loop through the array. works perfectly with just one row and more.